# Are watches asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I watch a variable `radioStatus` in a `Vue` instance:

```
watch: {
    radioStatus: function(val) {
      if (!this.discovery) {
        $.ajax({ url: '/switch/api/radio/' + (val ? 'on' : 'off') })
      }
    }
```

It may be modified in an AJAX call triggered upon page reload:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/api",
  cache: false
})
  .done(function(response) {
    vm.discovery = true;
    vm.radioStatus = response.radio.ison;  // <-- the change I mention below is here
    vm.discovery = false;
  });
```

**Can I assume that all of the method triggered by a `radioStatus` change will be completed before going to the next line (namely `vm.discovery = false`)?**

My concern is with the fact that `vm.discovery` is a flag used by several watched variables (in the same way as `radioStatus`) and that it will flip before the functions of the watched variables are finished.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, watchers are asynchronous. Ref: https://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Quoted from above link:

> **Watchers**
>
> While computed properties are... *This is most useful when you want to perform asynchronous or expensive operations in response to changing data.*

In your case above, the `vm.discovery = false;` will be completed before going into `watch`. If you are setting `vm.discovery` to `false`, then your ajax call inside `radioStatus` will always get executed.

To avoid that, you may try `vm.$nextTick()` as follows:

```
$.ajax({url: "/api", cache: false})
    .done(function(response) {
        vm.discovery = true;
        vm.radioStatus = response.radio.ison;
        vm.$nextTick( () => {
            console.log("Setting vm.discovery to false");
            vm.discovery = false;
        });
    });
```

It is again a tricky thing to do - because your `radioStatus()` callback in `watch` is also going to happen in the `nextTick` only. But assuming watch is triggered by the previous line itself (`vm.radioStatus = ...`), technically it should go into the queue first, and therefore get completed earlier. You will have to confirm with a series of `console.log` statements.