# How to watch only after the initial load from API in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am getting data from API with which I am populating the form in my component. I need to trigger watchers only after the initial populating of data. Like in async way. But the watcher is getting triggered immediately. I need to disable the Update button only if any value is changed after the initial populating of data.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-model="user.userId" /> <br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" v-model="user.title" /> <br />
    <br />
    <button :disabled="isDisabled">Update</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  watch: {
    user: {
      handler(oldVal, newVal) {
        if (oldVal != newVal) {
          this.isLoaded = false;
        }
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled() {
      return this.isLoaded;
    },
  },
  async created() {
    await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.user = json;
        this.isLoaded = true;
      });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      user: {
        userId: 0,
        id: 0,
        title: "",
        completed: false,
      },
      isLoaded: true,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I have referred [Vue, await for Watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63188422/vue-await-for-watch) and [Are watches asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321994/are-watches-asynchronous) and [Vue.js How to watcher before mounted() , can't get data from watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61211974/vue-js-how-to-watcher-before-mounted-cant-get-data-from-watch) but I am unable to follow.

Here's a preview : https://codesandbox.io/embed/great-euler-skd3v?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer for the question:

> Q: How to watch only after the initial load from API in VueJS?
>
> A: Add flag inside your `watch` (e.g. `isLoaded`).

Also there is couple things wrong with your code:

- `async/await` in `created` does nothing,
- `isDisabled` is not needed cause is basing only on 1 value from `data`. You can just use this value instead (`isLoading`).
- If you api calls fail, `isLoading` flag will not change, better approach is to move it to [finally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally).

Solution of your problem ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-platform-i1trj?file=/src/App.vue)) :

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-if="!isFetching">
      <input type="text" v-model="user.userId" /> <br />
      <br />
      <input type="text" v-model="user.title" /> <br />
      <br />
      <button :disabled="!isLoaded">Update</button>
    </div>
    <div v-else>Loading...</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      user: {
        userId: 0,
        id: 0,
        title: "",
        completed: false,
      },
      isFetching: false,
      isLoaded: false
    };
  },
  watch: {
    user: {
      handler(oldVal, newVal) {
        if (!this.isFetching) {
          // this comparision doesn't work (cause oldVal/newVal is an object)
          if (oldVal != newVal) {
            this.isLoaded = false;
          }
        }
      },
      deep: true
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.isFetching = true;
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.user = json;
        this.isLoaded = true;
      })
      .finally(() => this.isFetching = false)
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for trying. Even in this case, the disable button is always disabled. Please check the codesandbox link. I copy pasted your answer

Comment: @GrandWhiz Please check again, it works fine for me. Please notice that your comparision inside watch won't work cause you are comparing object using equal operator. Unless there is some misunderstood. Remove `if (oldVal != newVal)` and it work as expected.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this much. But, can you share a working codesandbox or codepen? The Update button is either enabled always or either disabled always :( ( I even copy pasted this answer in my codesandbox)

Comment: @GrandWhiz
Added codesandbox. Remember about comment about comparision you should either remove this condition or replace it with a working object comparision approach.

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be determined with some condition.

`isLoaded` already serves the purpose of determining the state of initial loading, but the name is confusing, because it determines that data is **not** loaded.

It can be:

```
  watch: {
    user: {
      if (this.isLoading && oldVal != newVal) {
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
      ...
```

The watcher doesn't need to be `deep` and could be unwatched when it's not needed:

```
async created() {
  let unwatchUser = this.$watch('user', (oldVal, newVal) => {
    if (this.isLoading && oldVal != newVal) {
      this.isLoading = false;
      unwatchUser();
    }
  })
  ...
```

A common way to designate that data hasn't been loaded yet is to set it to `null`, i.e. no value. This doesn't need `isLoading` flag or a watcher. If `null` is undesirable because of referred object properties, this can be overcome with optional chaining and conditional rendering:

```
  <div v-if="user">
      <input type="text" v-model="user.userId" />
      ...
  <div v-else class="spinner"/>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. If you don't mind, can you give the complete structure? you have mentioned watcher twice so I am unable to follow

Comment: I added a bit of context. You need to have a watcher either in `watch` or `created`, not both.

Comment: still facing the same issue. I have attached the codesandbox link. Please check that the update button is always disabled

Comment: What is the purpose of isLoaded here? You already have isFetching that reflects the state of data loading.